# Difference between "von", "aus", and "über"

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context, usage

> - Von diesem Land hatte ich bisher noch nie etwas gehört.
> - Aus diesem Land hatte ich bisher noch nie etwas gehört.
> - Über dieses Land hatte ich bisher noch nie etwas gehört.

How to know which one is correct in the given sentences, as all three of them mean the same thing:

> I had never heard of this country before.

I know that *von* is used for less details and *über* for more details. But, in the examples given, I am not sure about the usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Von diesem Land hatte ich bisher noch nie etwas gehört.

I had never heard *of that country* before.

I never knew of its existence

> Aus diesem Land hatte ich bisher noch nie etwas gehört.

I had never heard anything *originating from that country* before.

example context: I have been receiving reports from countries A, B, and C, but not from country X

> Über dieses Land hatte ich bisher noch nie etwas gehört.

I had never heard anything *about that country* before.

Depending on context, you might be previously aware of the existence of the country when you state that.
Example (from a sports perspective deliberately ridiculous but otherwise valid) :

"Nicaragua, Ecuador und Guatemala haben gute Eishockey-Teams"

"Stimmt, Nicaragua und Ecuador waren im Finale der WM ... aber über Guatemala habe ich im Zusammenhang mit Eishockey noch nie etwas gehört."

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you for the clarification :)